# css3 animation/transition/transform: How to make image grow?

Tags: animation, resize, css

I want to make my image grow to 1500px in height (and hopefully the width would just automatically re-size itself, if not, I could easily set it too)

I was using jquery .animate() but its just too choppy for my liking...
I know I can use the :

```
-webkit-transform: scale(2);
```

But I want it to be set to a specific size.. not just double or triple the image size.

Any help?

Thanks

Comment: jQuery is too choppy? Its pretty much the fastest you can get with javascript. What browser's do you need this to work for and what browser are you testing in?

Answer (score 16):

You're looking for the **-webkit-transition** property for webkit. That allows you to specify two separate CSS rules (for instance, two classes) and then the type of transition to be applied when switching those rules.

In this case, you could simply define the start and end heights (I did both height and width in the example below) as well as defining **-webkit-transition-property** for the properties you want transitioned, and **-webkit-transition-duration** for the duration:

```
div {
    height: 200px;
    width: 200px;
    -webkit-transition-property: height, width;
    -webkit-transition-duration: 1s;
    -moz-transition-property: height, width;
    -moz-transition-duration: 1s;
    transition-property: height, width;
    transition-duration: 1s;
    background: red;
}

div:hover {
    width: 500px;
    height: 500px;
    -webkit-transition-property: height, width;
    -webkit-transition-duration: 1s;
    -moz-transition-property: height, width;
    -moz-transition-duration: 1s;
    transition-property: height, width;
    transition-duration: 1s;
    background: red;
}
```

Tested in Safari. The Safari team also posted a pretty good write-up on [CSS Visual Effects](https://developer.apple.com/library/safari/documentation/InternetWeb/Conceptual/SafariVisualEffectsProgGuide/Introduction.html).

However, I would also recommend having another look at jQuery, as the newer CSS3 stuff won't be fully compatible with versions of IE.