# Image Enlarge Shrink Animation In JS

Tags: javascript, html, image, shrink

Ok so I'm putting in an image that onclick resizes, (goes larger and then onclick returns to origional size)

I've done this using JS but I cant seem to implicate an animation in the tween between sizes, i want it to visibly get bigger rather so it expands to the size rather than just flicks between the two instances.

Heres the coding:

```
      <script type="text/javascript">
<!--
var flag = true;
function resize() {
    if(flag) {
        document.getElementById("img1").style.width = "50px";
    } else {
        document.getElementById("img1").style.width = "280px";
    }
    (flag)?flag=false:flag=true;
} 
//-->
</script>

<body onload="resize();">
<img id="img1" src="../images/attachicona.png" border="0" onClick="resize();" />
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

if using jquery

```
var flag = true;
$('#img1').click(function(e){
    if(flag)
        $(e.target).animate({width:'50px'}, 150, function(){
            //do stuff after animation
        });

    else
        $(e.target).animate({width:'280px'}, 150, function(){
            //do stuff after animation
        });
    flag=!flag;
});
```

Answer (score 2):

You can use CSS3 transitions to make the same effect. No need of javascript or jquery - 
[css3 animation/transition/transform: How to make image grow?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3620587/css3-animation-transition-transform-how-to-make-image-grow)

Or you can use jquery animations - 
http://forum.jquery.com/topic/image-resize-animation

Comment: I know i was going to do that, but it doesnt work for mobile, the hover effect stays on. I want to be able to toggle the transition with a click rather than a hover. Cheers

Comment: You can try jquery animations. Pretty simple to use. (see updated answer)